# How can I unlink duplicated objects so I can animate them independently?

Tags: animation

So I duplicated an object and it seems that I can only edit the animation on the "mother" object. That means both of them are using the same animation. I wanted to animate them independently.
I tried *object>relations>make single user* but it doesn't seem to do anything. Am I doing something wrong? [image]

Comment: your rig isn't setup correctly at all...you haven't applied scale/rotations. If you try to move your original mesh/armature, it ends in a mess. That's why copying doesn't work eiter....

Comment: and you origin points are just "somewhere" but not where it would make sense. Did you make the rig or did you get it from somewhere? If you made it on your own i would recommend watching some beginner rigging tutorials where you can learn what applying scale and rotation means and how you can use it.

Comment: unfortunately my rigging knowledge is too low to clean up that mess...but i am sure Josh could...hopefully he will help....

Comment: Thank you. I am a complete begginner. I'll try to deal with this mess first and then duplicate the object. Hopefully this will work

Comment: It should no problem, we all started some day. If you make a „clean „ rig, you can move it around and neither the armature nor  the mesh would mess up. Then the duplicating will work  maybe you should start with a less complicated rig just to see how it works 